# I keep getting an error with the e4tools package?

Tags: wearables

I keep getting an error with the e4tools package. It is during part 4 of the code. Anyone know how to fix this?

Error in names(EDA_Binned_Merged) <- c("ID", "PressTime", "BeforeAfter",  :
attempt to set an attribute on NULL

I also tried using their example data and got the same error, so I don't think it's an issue with my data.